# PHP echo elements from nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, printing

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( [internalName] => novoleto1 
        [title] => Novo leto 
        [date] => Date Object ( 
                  [year] => 2015 
                  [month] => 01 
                  [day] => 01 
                  [hour] => 0 
                  [minute] => 0 
                  [second] => 0 
                  [partsecond] => 0 
                  [tz] => Date_TimeZone Object ( 
                          [id] => CEST 
                          [longname] => Central European Time 
                          [shortname] => CET 
                          [hasdst] => 1 
                          [dstlongname] => Central European Summer Time 
                          [dstshortname] => CEST 
                          [offset] => 3600000 
                          [default] => 
                        ) 
                  [getWeekdayAbbrnameLength] => 3 
                ) 
       )
```

How can I print all the elements seperately? I cant only echo title and internal name, but how can I print elements of date object?

Comment: You can use print_r($array) to print arrays, or use your own function if you need something specific.

Comment: Do you want to print them all in a loop or do you just want to know how to reference `an object in an array` or `an object in an object in an array`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the whole array with its structure for debugging purpose, then just dump it:

```
var_dump($my_array);
```

If you want to access specific elements, then access the object property:

```
echo $my_array['Novo leto']->year;
```

Note that `$my_array['Novo leto']` is an object, *not* an array.

Certainly you can also combine properties:

```
echo sprintf('%s-%s-%s', 
    $my_array['Novo leto']->year, 
    $my_array['Novo leto']->month, 
    $my_array['Novo leto']->day
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use this array element like a object.

```
$year = $yourArray['date']->year;
echo $year;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print them all separately, you can use a foreach loop :

```
<?php

foreach ($myArray as $value)
{
    if (is_array($value) || is_object($value))
        print_r($value); // You can also use var_dump
    else
        echo $value;
}
```